# Copy Area and Paste Area Aren't The Same Size Error?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I want the VBA to find the cell header named "Apple" (in row a1) in Sheet1 and paste that data into cell header named "Orange in Sheet2

```
Sheet1     Sheet2

Apple      Orange
1
2
3
4
```

I am trying to NOT include cell header so it only grabs the number.

Would something like below work?

```
Sheet1.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="Apple", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Selection.EntireColumn row-1.Copy sheet2.range("a2")
```

Something like `entirecolumn row -1` so that it doesn't copy the header cell...
not sure what I am doing but help would be great!

Comment: @pnuts That's a clever way to do this. Assuming, of course, there's not important data in `a1`.

Comment: You cannot change the question completely after getting answers (btw, in mine, your new question was already solved). I will delete my answer now (because of not liking your attitude).

Comment: @pnuts Has he selected as the right one an answer recommending to write ";" at the end of a VBA line?! (and saying that it does not work; and having another answerer delivering a working answer?) Wow! Now I understand a lot, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With this command: `c = ActiveCell.Column` you are setting `c` to be the entire column of the currently active cell.  Next, when you use `s1.Columns(c).Copy s2.Range("a2")` you are copying the entire column stored in `c`, and then attempting to paste it into the 2nd cell in the specified column's range (`a2`).  This results in it always having one less cell than you copied to the clipboard.

Comment: Sorry to correct you but the only responsible bit is s1.Columns(c). c = ActiveCell.Column does not have any influence. c = 1 would have do exactly the same.

Comment: True, but that was where I perceived the misunderstanding to take place.  I read this as they were assuming that the column would be copied only where they had selected, but then they passed in an entire column's reference in the copy/paste command.  I have updated my answer to be a little more clear on this.

Comment: Good. I saw it otherwise: my impression was that what the OP wants is to copy the range resulting from the "Find" above. More specifically, he wants to copy one column of this range (formed, presumably, by various columns). He is most likely mistaken regarding the exact definition of the column (c) too. He thought that just by executing Find s1.Columns(c) would be accounting for the outputted range instead of for the whole spreadsheet.